# Proposed edits are all shown as owned by "anonymous user"

Tags: bug, status-completed

I started noticing this yesterday. Every proposed edit is showing that it is proposed by an anonymous user. There is no way to determine which account is proposing the edit.

However, after accepting or rejecting the edit, the user's account is then shown.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Fixed in the code already, we just haven't published yet.